# Split a csv file into parts, copy header

Tags: bash, sed, split

I want a quick way to split a csv file into N roughly equal parts and make each part have the original header as the first line.
So far I've come up with this, which works (N=5):

```
split -da 4 -l $((`wc -l < foo.csv`/5)) foo.csv foo --additional-suffix=".csv"
for f in `ls foo0*.csv`;do sed -i "1s/^/`head -n 1 foo.csv`\n/" $f; done;
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to turn this into a one-liner where I feed the newly created files by split into the for loop instead of running the ls command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a for loop at all. You can simply do this:

```
sed -i "1s/^/`head -n 1 foo.csv`\n/" foo0*.csv
```

I don't think you can feed the newly created files through `sed` because `split` doesn't give you the new filenames.

If you really want a one-liner, you can join the two statements with `&&`:

```
split -da 4 -l $((`wc -l < foo.csv`/5)) foo.csv foo --additional-suffix=".csv" && sed -i "1s/^/`head -n 1 foo.csv`\n/" foo0*.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a one-liner, but it ensures the header is not in any of the split files, then adds it to all.

```
f=foo.csv
header=$(sed 1q "$f")
split -da 4 -l $(( ($(wc -l < "$f")-1) / 5 )) <(sed 1d "$f") foo --additional-suffix=".csv"
sed -i "1i\\$header" foo0*.csv
```

Comment: Right, I shouldn't add the header to foo0000.txt twice, which is what the original code is doing.