# Multicore gzip uncompression with spliting output file (csv) to parts by 1Gb/file

Tags: csv, gzip, bigdata

I have 10Gb gzip archive (uncompressed is about 60Gb).

Is there a way to decompress this file with multithreading + on the fly splitting output to parts by 1Gb/part (n-lines/part, [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954480/split-a-csv-file-into-parts-copy-header))?

If I do something like this:

```
pigz -dc 60GB.csv.gz | dd bs=8M skip=0 count=512 of=4G-part-1.csv
```

I can get a 4Gb file, but it don't care about starting always from next line, so lines in my files won't be ended properly.

Also, as I notised, my GCE instance with persistant disk has maximum 33kb block size, so I can't actually use command like above, but have to print something like:

```
pigz -dc 60GB.csv.gz | dd bs=1024 skip=0 count=4194304 of=4G-part-1.csv

pigz -dc 60GB.csv.gz | dd bs=1024 skip=4194304 count=4194304 of=4G-part-2.csv

pigz -dc 60GB.csv.gz | dd bs=1024 skip=$((4194304*2)) count=4194304 of=4G-part-3.csv
```

So, I have to make some trick to always start file from new line..

**UPDATE:**

```
zcat 60GB.csv.gz |awk 'NR%43000000==1{x="part-"++i".csv";}{print > x}'
```

did the trick.

Comment: Do you have enough memory (i.e. ~10GB) to hold this file?

Comment: I'll get some, if I'll get a working mothod to do this.

Comment: I'd suggest that you get the memory first and see what's the performance then. This question may become null and void with the kind of performance you get when you give the application sufficient memory. Especially with 'BigData', the entire system limps down when memory is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sizes you mention in your question, it looks like you get about 6-to-1 compression.  That doesn't seem great for text, but anyway...

As Mark states, you can't just dip mid stream into your gz file and expect to land on a new line.  Your `dd` options won't work because dd only copies bytes, it doesn't detect compressed newlines.  If indexing is out of scope for this, the following command line solution might help:

```
$ gzcat 60GB.csv.gz | awk -v n=1 '!NR%20000000{n++} {print|("gzip>part-"n".gz")}'
```

This decompresses your file so that we can count lines, then processes the stream, changing the output file name every 20000000 lines.  You can adjust your recompression options where you see "gzip" in the code above.

If you don't want your output to be compressed, you can simplify the last part of the line:

```
$ gzcat 60GB.csv.gz | awk -v n=1 '!NR%3500000{n++} {print>("part-"n".csv")}'
```

You might have to play with the number of lines to get something close to the file size you're aiming for.

Note that if your shell is csh/tcsh, you may have to escape the exclamation point in the awk script to avoid it being interpreted as a history reference.

**UPDATE**:

If you'd like to get status of what the script is doing, awk can do that.  Something like this might be interesting:

```
$ gzcat 60GB.csv.gz | awk -v n=1 '!NR%3500000{n++} !NR%1000{printf("part=%d / line=%d\r",n,NR)} {print>("part-"n".csv")}'
```

This should show you the current part and line number every thousand lines.

Comment: tnx, m8, this is a good one.. But can you help me just one more time, i'm not very familiar with awk, and just can't get command to create several files with 2000000 lines: it only creates one big file part-1.csv and prints everything to it.

Comment: Hrm. That's strange. How many lines are in the file, anyway?  (`gzcat file.gz | wc -l` will tell you.) The condition `!NR%20000000` should indeed evaluate as true once every twenty million lines.  Can you try reducing the number to something easily visible, like a few thousand, and see if you get lots of files?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a variation to the awk command which should give you feedback on the progress of your run.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it was especially prepared for such an operation, or unless an index was built for that purpose, then no.  The gzip format inherently requires the decompression of the data before any point in the stream, in order to decompress data after that point in the stream.  So it cannot be parallelized.

The way out is to either a) recompress the gzip file with synchronization points and save those locations, or b) go through the entire gzip file once and create another file of entry points with the previous context at those points.

For a), [zlib](http://zlib.net) provides `Z_FULL_FLUSH` operations that insert synchronization points in the stream from which you can start decompression with no previous history.  You would want to create such points sparingly, since they degrade compression.

For b), [zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c) provides an example of how to build in index into a gzip file.  You need to go through the stream once in serial order to build the index, but having done so, you can then start decompression at the locations you have saved.

Comment: I [heard](http://serverfault.com/a/270825/239809) pigz can provide multithread-like way to decompress gz, as while it uses a single thread for decompression, it starts 3 additional threads for reading, writing, and check calculation.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, it seems like I don't get your point (my English isn't good enough)

Comment: pigz provides only a small speedup on decompression with multiple processors, due to the serial nature of gzip streams.  However pigz provides a factor of _n_ speedup when compressing on _n_ processors.